# Rich gui in MFC/C++ application

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

we have once application build using MFC/C++. We want make the bit rich UI like VS 2010 or outlook etc... at last we want give new look to our app like Microsoft does on every release of their products.

Please suggest me to topic that i need to look into or suggest me the option for the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 or higher, the MFC application wizard itself will generate UI like VS 2010 with tabs and docking windows. In fact you can create an application that looks like VS 2010 without writing a single line of code. There is also support for the ribbon control which has replaced the menus in the new office applications.

Comment: also, if I understand correctly, you already have some code in MFC. You'll be able to reuse it in straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

As I am assuming you are going to use C++/native code, MFC is still the way to go or you can choose the WTL also. If you are ready yo go to a totally different direction then QT is one of the most advanced and modern cross platform library. MFC feels old compared to QT. AFAIK you can not use ribbon control in QT without microsoft license.
Another option is to go to managed way, you can use WPF with C#.

Comment: 'MFC feels old', why? All the latest operating system features and look and feel are available.

Comment: I was not talking in terms of end user experience. MFC was designed in 90's. It's coding structure and conventions are old compared to QT.

Comment: You are right Tinku, however, considers that a library with two decades of experience that supports the latest features in terms of user experience and stability, if you work only on windows is unbeatable.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can use the new classes in the [MFC feature pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982354%28v=vs.90%29), which came with Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1.

MSDN provided a tutorial how to migrate an old MFC application to the new MFC feature pack classes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983935%28v=vs.90%29.aspx